# about docker link and container's /etc/hosts file

Tags: networking, docker

I am following the docker official doc"[Linking Containers Together](http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/)". At the bottom of this doc, on the container's /etc/hosts file, it defines ip address for both ends of a link.

```
$ sudo docker run -t -i --rm --link db:db training/webapp /bin/bash
root@aed84ee21bde:/opt/webapp# cat /etc/hosts
172.17.0.7  aed84ee21bde
. . .
172.17.0.5  db
```

And then, it says:

If you restart the source container, the linked containers /etc/hosts files will be automatically updated with the source container's new IP address, allowing linked communication to continue.

```
$ sudo docker restart db
db
$ sudo docker run -t -i --rm --link db:db training/webapp /bin/bash
root@aed84ee21bde:/opt/webapp# cat /etc/hosts
172.17.0.7  aed84ee21bde
. . .
172.17.0.9  db
```

I am wandering, what about the link created before container 'db' restart, the old recipient's /etc/hosts file still keep 'db' old ip, but after 'db' container's ip changed after it restarted, the /etc/hosts file lost its effect.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known bug in docker that affects some versions of it [#6350](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/6350). Also some versions of docker has this problem when you are using link aliases. So if you upgrade your docker to latest version (currently 1.8.1) the problem can be solved.